# Strange behavior when mixing indirect expansion and parameter transformation in Bash

Tags: bash, indirection

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66897754/4184203), I can check whether an array is indexed or associative as follows:

```bash
$ declare -a a
$ declare -A b
$ echo ${a@a}
a
$ echo ${b@a}
A
```

If I use indirect expansion, however, it doesn't work:

```bash
$ var=a
$ echo ${!var@a}

$ var=b
$ echo ${!var@a}

$
```

Yet, if I initialize the arrays, it now works again:

```bash
$ a=()
$ b=()
$ var=a
$ echo ${!var@a}
a
$ var=b
$ echo ${!var@a}
A
$
```

Is this intended behavior or is it a Bash bug?

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
[...]
```

Comment: The canonical place for "feature or a bug?" questions for places where the documentation is silent is the bash-bug mailing list (https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/). Unless the question has already been asked there, there may not _exist_ any canonical statement.

Comment: (That said, _insofar as the documentation is silent_, I'd argue that it's in unspecified space -- neither a feature nor a bug, but undefined behavior that's subject to change without notice)

Comment: fwiw, a nameref (`bash 4.2+`) appears to work as expected when arrays are declared but not yet populated: `declare -n arr=a; echo ${arr@a} ==> a` / `declare -n arr=b; echo ${arr@a} ==> A`

Comment: @jhnc not sure what the issue is on your system; I get the posted results with *a)* `bash 5.0.17(1) / Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS`, *b)* `bash 5.1.16(1) / Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS` and *c)* `bash 5.2.15(3) / cygwin 3.4.9-1`